# Redirecting old url traffic to new url using htaccess and 301 permanent moved

Tags: html, .htaccess, redirect

I'm trying to change the old url of a website to the new one using the 301 permanently moved directive through .htaccess

I wanted to change all the traffic to the new url and I also wanted to tell search engines the new address of some pages (which url changed)

I used

```
Redirect 301 / http://www.newdomain.com/
Redirect 301 /page1.html http://www.newdomain.com/page1/
Redirect 301 /page2.html http://www.newdomain.com/page2/
Redirect 301 /page3.html http://www.newdomain.com/page3/
```

But the result that I'm getting is that the last threee directives are redirecting to

```
http://www.newdomain.com/page1.html and so
```

Is there something that I'm missing here or that I need to do to redirect the traffic and also tell which will be the new urls for each page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually managed to fix this by reorganizing the htaccess content

```
Redirect 301 /page1.html http://www.newdomain.com/page1/
Redirect 301 /page2.html http://www.newdomain.com/page2/
Redirect 301 /page3.html http://www.newdomain.com/page3/
RedirectMatch 301 /(.*) http://www.domaintoredirecto.com1
```

worked...